# COBOL Data Type Conversion

Tags: cobol

I'm working to document the COBOL data type COMP, COMP-1, COMP-2, COMP-3 to ASCII conversion.  I have been searching for a conversion table.  I tried the IBM sites and could not find one.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The formats of `COMP`, `COMP-1`, `COMP-2`, and `COMP-3` are implementor-defined. `COMP`, while normally defined as `BINARY`, may be implemented as `DISPLAY`, `BINARY`, or `PACKED-DECIMAL`. `COMP-3` is normally the same as `PACKED-DECIMAL`, but some systems may not include the "sign" nibble for unsigned values. `COMP-1` and `COMP-2` are normally defined as floating-point, but may be hexadecimal floating-point or IEEE floating-point. Furthermore, signed ASCII `DISPLAY` may have leading or trailing signs encoded as part of the value. More and specific detail is required.

Comment: Hello Rick.  Thanks so much for your reply.  Based on what you have written, I have come to the conclusion I need to send the data to the file using Display.  Not relying on a conversion table.  Thanks again.

Comment: Conversion to `DISPLAY` with a separate leading sign and decimal separator is to be preferred whenever possible. This also allows easier conversion from EBCDIC to ASCII, if that is a consideration.

Comment: It is a concentration Rick.  Thank you for the tip.